# start GRASS 7.6.1 with OpenCl from windows prompt

Tags: grass-gis

I desperately tried this code and variations:

```
grass76  LOCATION_NAME=32632  GISDBASE=C:\Users\706774\Desktop\xxx\grass_database  MAPSET=PERMANENT  --with-opencl  --gu
```

but I get this error:

> ERROR: Location  doesn't exist Exiting...

Someone could be so kind to help me?

Answer (score 1):

In order to start GRASS **and** create a new LOCATION at the same time, you must supply the `-c` parameter with one of three items on the command line:

1. The EPSG code of the coordinate system you want for the new LOCATION
2. A georeferenced data file: GRASS will read the coordinate system from that file and create a suitable LOCATION
3. Nothing (**not recommended**), in which case a LOCATION with no projection information is create

So try:

```
grass76 -c EPSG:xxxx LOCATION_NAME=32632  GISDBASE=C:\Users\706774\Desktop\xxx\grass_database  MAPSET=PERMANENT  --with-opencl  --gui
```

where xxxx is the EPSG code of the coordinate system you want to use.

or

```
grass76 -c your_geotiff.tif LOCATION_NAME=32632  GISDBASE=C:\Users\706774\Desktop\xxx\grass_database  MAPSET=PERMANENT  --with-opencl  --gui
```

where "your_geotiff.tif" is some georeferenced data file you have

Comment: ok, with the first code it works, but WITHOUT "GISDBASE=" before c:

Comment: intead, if i want to use my EXISTING database: grass76  LOCATION_NAME=32632  C:\Users\706774\Desktop\xxx\grass_database  MAPSET=PERMANENT  --with-opencl  --gui          gives me this error: ERROR: <C:\Users\706774\Desktop> is not a valid GRASS Location because PERMANENT Mapset is missing